# Jquery needs a timeout of 0ms to find element in vue.js component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm using Jquery inside a vue component. And I need to the assign `#container` with a another function through jquery. The `#container` is only there when the type is not default. It's a realy preformance intensive function so I realy only want it to assign it when needed. With a work around `timeout` of 0ms it works.

But is there a better / cleaner way to do?

```
Vue.component( 'component', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            typeOpt: "default"
        }
    },
    watch: {
        typeOpt: function( newVal ) {
            if( newVal !== "default" )
            {
                setTimeout(function () { //When I remove this it will not update the e.g. background color
                    $('#container').css( "background", "red" );
                }, 0);
            }
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div class='component'>
            <select v-on:change="changeType">
                <option :selected="typeOpt === 'default'" value="default">Default</option>
                <option :selected="typeOpt === 'type1'" value="type1">Type1</option>
            </select>

            <div class='mainContainer'>
                <div v-if="typeOpt == 'default'">default</div>
                <div v-if="typeOpt == 'type1'">
                    <div id='container'>content 123 ABC</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        changeType() {
            this.typeOpt = $('select').val();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: *"But is there a better / cleaner way to do?"* Yeah, get rid of jQuery. Everything you have here can be achieved using standard Vue functionality. Bind your `select` element to your `typeOpt` property and use a style binding for the background color. You can get rid of your watcher and your method.

Comment: `$('#container').css( "background", "red" );` is just a jquery placeholder function. As I wrote the real function is `[...] realy preformance intensive [...]` With difrent subfunction... So that is no a option.

Comment: The `setTimeout()` pushes the inside method into the event loop which will cause it to run after all other processes have been run (i.e. rendering of the component and such). Vue's onboard mechanism would be using [`vm.$nextTick()`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) to wait for the DOM to be rendered before executing it.